# Vb.net - Cross-threading exception when opening the form

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, forms

I have created two forms, in which one form to display the last modified record and another form which gives search result of current form. But some times when searching records "No result can happened" , in that situation i am closing the search form and opening the "Last record showing form"

Searching :

Menu find click

```
 frmSearch.Show()
 frm.Hide()
```

if no records find then, i am invoking "Begin invoke method" to close and show "Form Last record"

```
Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf CloseMethod))

Sub CloseMethod()
     frmSearch.Close()
     frm.Show()
end sub
```

But in "Frm.show" i am getting **Error - Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on**

Also when i change the method as

```
 Sub CloseMethod()
         frmSearch.Close()
         frm.Close()
         frm.Show()
 end sub
```

i am not getting the error. Please any one help me understand why i am getting error.

Comment: Create your `frmSearch` instance in the same thread as that of `frm` and you won't get that error.  Another option is to break out the method into two parts, one that operates on `frmSearch` and another that operates on `frm`.  Then you'd use `frm.BeginInvoke()` instead of `Me.BeginInvoke()` for the latter that works with `frm`.

Comment: All your UI work should be done on the UI thread and only the actual search should be performed on a secondary thread.  You might look at using a `BackgroundWorker`, which allows you to handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to do something on the UI thread when the background work is complete.

Comment: All form instances are managed in mdiform. even though i am facing the work. can u please explain what is the error happening and why?